# Enable mirroring on iPhone 4 (over-the-air)

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, airplay

Through a cydia tweak or otherwise, is it possible to enable over-the-air mirroring for unsupported-by-default devices, i.e. iPhone 4, iPad 1 et al.?

You would think it's a popular question but all google results result in a dead end. The closest I've come to finding an answer is [this](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/airplay-mirroring-on-older-devices.366920/) topic, where an user claims to have come up with a solution, but then dies*.

Considering people managed to even port Siri for the iPhone 4, I'm sure someone must have made a successful attempt at enabling mirroring, which I guess only involves flipping a switch, i.e. no authorization checks, proxies, and missing binary files here. What I'm trying to say is I'm surprised there's nothing out there.

**or which is more likely, goes offline and refuses to share, whatever - the point is, no solution is given.*

Comment: What do you want to mirror where?

Comment: Allow me to quote myself: _"I'm looking for a way to enable the native mirroring ability, so that I can mirror my iPhone 4 on my Apple TV, just like I would with an iPhone 4S."_

Comment: Do you consider this question to be unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that does exactly what you're asking for. However, [this](http://screensplitr.com/about/) should be similar. I've stumbled upon it in Cydia a few times, but never bothered to try it, because AirPlay just never appealed to me. It's not explicitly AirPlay Mirroring, but it does the same thing. There's also a package called Display Mirroring and DisplayOut found in Cydia, and they enable mirroring, but it's not over-the-air (you have to use a VGA adapter). There's also another Cydia package called [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/), and it allows your iOS device to receive media from your Mac or another iOS device through AirPlay.

Comment: It's not quite what I'm looking for. ScreenSplitr only lets you mirror your iPhone onto a mac using another app, iDemo. I'm looking for a way to enable the native mirroring ability, so that I can mirror my iPhone 4 on my Apple TV, just like I would with an iPhone 4S.

Comment: There's nothing that does that, sorry. I posted what I could find as the closest thing to what you were asking for. I updated my answer to mention that it doesn't do exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you plz go into details a bit - why you're so sure there's nothing doing that? On the one hand iP4s does it natively whereas iP4 cannot, having mostly the same other features related to AirPlay and Apple-TV (moreover we learned from Siri porting that nothing is impossible for iP4 if that is not processor-dependent task).
On the other hand - you mentioned that AirPlay never really appealed to you...maybe you just missed smth from the subject?

Comment: @Nullinsworth I'm an active JailBreak freak. I know almost every tweak available (even from obscure repositories), and I've personally tried most of them. From my knowledge and diligent searching, I could not find anything that enabled AirPlay on non-iPhone 4S/iPad 2 devices. AirPlay seems useful, but not useful to me. I don't own an Apple TV, and I don't see a need to own one; I just don't have time in my schedule for much entertainment. I'd rather play a rousing game of Halo than watch a slideshow mirrored to my TV. It's a personal preference, but I *do* see the genius that is AirPlay.

Answer (score 0):

I used Veency when I want to display my iPhone screen on another screen for, say, displaying funcationality and so on - it's not very fast so video and camera use are pretty rough, but it works nicely for me :)